# Error stabilisation control (ESC) and Error start stop

Tags: troubleshooting, electronic-stability-control

I have just had my front lower wishbones changed,two new tyres, and whilst driving today these error  messages came up.

- Error - stabilisation control (ESC)
- Error - start-stop.

What can I do as I need my car for work and cant get to the garage until Friday afternoon.

Comment: It may be that those two errors mean that the ESC won't work and that the start-stop won't work either - (where the engine stops at traffic lights and re-starts automatically). Without knowing exactly what the fault is, it could be that it may be safe to drive without those functions but, also there may be other associated errors such as ABS not working either. Until the actual fault is identified then you should assume it is not safe to drive...

Answer (score 0):

What make/model/year of vehicle?

My first approach would be to call the people who did the work; tell them to come and pick up the car and give you a loaner while they plug in the cables they disconnected.

Comment: Or damaged the reluctor rings